# Unable to access elements using White framework

Tags: c#, automated-tests, white-framework

I get unauthorized access exception while trying to get application windows using TestStack.White framework. 
Below is the exception:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in
>   UIAutomationClient.dll
>
> Additional information: Access is denied

The code is here:

```
var loginScreen = application.GetWindows().Single();
```

It doesn't really matter which API I use for accessing the window, the result's the same.

The process runs in Windows 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which framework is used for the UI of your app? WPF, WinForms, etc.

Such code won't work too?

```
application.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("winAutoId"));
```